# C# to C++ : IntPtr.ToPointer , what is the C++ code?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
private unsafe void OnDataReady(IntPtr val)
{
    void** ptrs = (void**)val.ToPointer();
}
```

above is the C# code ,Now,I want to write it with C++,  what should i do ?
what is the C++ code ? Could any somebody good heart could help me ?
Thank you very much.
Best wishes for you.

Comment: just do int* myIn;

Comment: Won't any calls to this function just get optimized away?  It has no side effects, and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Why do you need a `void **`? There may be more idiomatic ways to accomplish the actual task in C++.

Comment: Other more ,the C# code use base to access father class :                                              if (Handler == IntPtr.Zero) return;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => base.AddSink());      what should use to instead "base"  in C++?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you use `std::intptr_t`:

```
#include <cstdint>

void OnDataReady(std::intptr_t val)
{
    void** ptrs = (void**)val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,I will try.